# Disposing Font Object in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dispose

I have the following code

```
Font font = ComboBox.Font;
if(condition1)
font = new Font(font, FontStyle.Bold);
if(condition2)
  e.Graphics.DrawString("One", font, color, rectangle);
else
  e.Graphics.DrawString("Two", font, color, rectangle);
font.Dispose();
```

When I run the code analysis, it shows an error that 'font' is not disposed along all exception paths. What's the proper way to dispose it in the above code?

Thanks.

Comment: Try a try..finally block.

Comment: Irrelevant to the question, but why would you want to dispose the font if `condition1` is false?

Comment: @Samuel try.. finally block solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ***should not Dispose*** `ComboBox.Font`: it should do `ComboBox` *itself*.
You can create a `Font` *copy* instead:

```
using (Font font = new Font(ComboBox.Font, condition1 ? FontStyle.Bold : ComboBox.Font.Style)) {
  if (condition2)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("One", font, color, rectangle);
  else
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Two", font, color, rectangle);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The clue is in the phrase "all exception paths". Essentially, Code analysis has noticed that an exception could be thrown by the `DrawString` calls, and that the `Dispose` would not be called in that case.

There is also the question of disposing an object which you did not create, so a simple flag would suffice there.

As Samuel noted in the comments, wrap the block in a `try...finally` and call `Dispose` in the `finally` block, like this:

```
Font font = ComboBox.Font;
bool created = false;

try
{
    if(condition1)
    {
        font = new Font(font, FontStyle.Bold);
        created = true;
    }
    if(condition2)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("One", font, color, rectangle);
    else
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Two", font, color, rectangle);
}
finally
{
    if (created)
        font.Dispose();
}
```

Code Analysis will still complain at this, as the `Dispose` is conditional on the value of `created`, and the code analysis tool is not sophisticated enough to be able to determine that the creation and disposal conditions are identical. The solution to that is shown in [Dmitry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24053925/3419534), specifically to create a new `Font` whatever the value of `condition1`, and to use that condition instead to choose the appropriate value within the font object.

Comment: I tried this with the bool flag, but it still shows the same warning.

Comment: @Vj87 I thought that might be the case. Dmitry's answer has the solution to that, so I've edited to acknowledge it.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is to only dispose the font if you have to create a new one. So this is the code you need to use:

```
Action<Font> drawString =
    f => e.Graphics.DrawString(condition2 ? "One" : "Two", f, color, rectangle);

if (condition1)
    drawString(ComboBox.Font);
else
    using (var font = new Font(ComboBox.Font, FontStyle.Bold))
    {
        drawString(font);
    }
```

Comment: +1. I like your approach. I would not use an action though, but refactor drawString to a new private method.